# Find the amplitude and period of the function. $y = 4 \sin(−6x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

Do I factor the $-6$ out then divide $2π/-6$ to get the period?

Comment: For a function of the form $A\sin (Bx-C)$ or $A\cos (Bx-C)$ the period is: $2\pi/B$. So you don't have to factor anything.

Comment: However, this is sin. The previous answer I gace was 12π. Is that right?

Comment: No, $2\pi/6=\pi/3\neq12\pi.$

Comment: Why is it not necessary for the 6 to be factored out the parentheses?

Comment: It isn't factored. We define the period to be $2\pi/B$ where we're considering the function $A\sin(Bx+C),B\gt0$. It doesn't factor out, it's different.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? So with the sine function it is not nccessary to factor out B? Only the cos function?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, can you clarify please?

Comment: I need to study more.

Comment: @user137452 You keep asking if you should "factor out" the 6.  If you mean what I think you mean, you should know that $\sin(-6x) \ne -6\sin(x)$.  The negative sign can be brought out (it's not "factoring" though) only because sine is an *odd function*, but don't think that any number can be pulled out of the sine function.  In fact, even the negative can't be pulled out of a cosine.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $f(x) = 4\sin(-6x) = -4\sin(6x)$. Thus, $T = \dfrac{2\pi}{6} = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$. The amplitude is $A = 4$.

Comment: So I need to factor out the negative sign, yet, the 6 stays within the paretheses?

Comment: The period is a positive number, so the negative sign is taken from within the function.

Comment: So the graph is inverted?

Comment: Yes.Yes, the zeros of the functions $f(x)=4\sin(6x)$ and $g(x)=-4\sin(6x)$ are equal, but the points of local maxima are the points of a local minimum of the other.

Answer (score 3):

I find helpful to think about physics here. If you have a periodic function like $\sin$ or $\cos$, a wave is given by $$y(x,t) = A\cos(kx - \omega t + \phi)$$
and the period is given by $T = 2\pi /\omega$. Also the wave length is given by $\lambda = 2 \pi/ k$.

Now, to your specific problem, $y = 4 \sin (-6x)$ would wield an amplitude equal to $4$, and period $2 \pi /6 = \pi/3$, since periods are always positive. Ok?

Comment: But why is it not necessary to factor out the 6?

Comment: I don't understand from *what* do you want to factor the $6$ out of. Writing a specific formula for $\sin(6(-x))$ is possible, but completely useless to the problem, here.